# How i can get index of image in div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some block ( it could be div or someting ect):

```
<pre>
<div>
<img src="#" onclick="showmeindex();">
<img src="#" onclick="showmeindex();">
<img src="#" onclick="showmeindex();">
<img src="#" onclick="showmeindex();">
</div>
</pre>
```

for example, like:

```
$array = array
(
$key => $value,
$key => $value,
$key => $value,
$key => $value
)
```

i need get $key each img in my function showmeindex();

thnx

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want the index of the clicked image. For that, don't use inline js. Instead do this

```
$('img').click(function(){
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

I do hope you know that indexes start from `0`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdq4s09a/)

Comment: thanx, i need exactly bing js at each img

Comment: @ПавелЯкушенков glad to have helped you!